# Turn Array with Key Values into JSON object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array in JavaScript that I use `JSON.stringify()` on that ends up looking like this after:

```
[  
   {  
      "typeOfLoan":"Home"
   },
   {  
      "typeOfResidency":"Primary"
   },
   {  
      "downPayment":"5%"
   },
   {  
      "stage":"Just Looking"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Jared"
   },
   {  
      "lastName":"Example"
   },
   {  
      "email":"Jared@demo.com"
   },
   {  
      "cell":"8888888888"
   },
   {  
      "loanofficer":"Jim Loan"
   }
]
```

I want the output to be a standard JSON object so that I can send it in a POST. Before this gets marked as duplicate, I have tried all of the answers I could possibly find already and they all end up not working or having syntax errors that I do not understand how to fix. This array is stored in variable `jsonArray`.

Comment: You had an array of objects, now you have a string - json. You can send either in a POST request. You should post the code you have and explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The array of objects, all with a single key, seems fishy. I suppose you want a single object literal with all the keys, which you can then send to you backend (and parse there). So first, reduce the many objects in a single one, then implement your ajax call to `POST` it to wherever. Here's how to reduce it:

```js
let arr = [{"typeOfLoan":"Home"},{"typeOfResidency":"Primary"},{"downPayment":"5%"},{"stage":"Just Looking"},{"firstName":"Jared"},{"lastName":"Example"},{"email":"Jared@demo.com"},{"cell":"8888888888"},{"loanofficer":"Jim Loan"}];

let res = arr.reduce((a,b) => {
  let key = Object.keys(b)[0];
  a[key] = b[key];
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Depending on what you use to send it to the backend, you might need to use `JSON.stringify` on `res`

Comment: the JavaScript seems to have an issue with the keyword `let`. It does not recognize it as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Before *stringifying*, convert your request payload from an array to an object.

```
const arr = [{"typeOfLoan":"Home"},{"typeOfResidency":"Primary"},{"downPayment":"5%"},{"stage":"Just Looking"},{"firstName":"Jared"},{"lastName":"Example"},{"email":"Jared@demo.com"},{"cell":"8888888888"},{"loanofficer":"Jim Loan"}];

const payload = arr.reduce(function(acc, prev){
  return Object.assign(acc, prev);
}, {});

console.log(payload);
```

Comment: I get this error: `"undefined is not a function (evaluating 'jsonArray.reduce(function(acc, prev){\n      return Object.assign(acc, prev);\n    }, {})')";`

Comment: Are you reducing on a string? What does `console.log(typeof  jsonArray)` print?